# A question from Stein's book, Singular Integral.

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

A question from Stein's book, Singular Integral. Let $\left\{ f_{m}\right\} $
be a sequence of integrable function such that $$\int_{%
\mathbb{R}^{d}}\left\vert f_{m}\left( y\right) \right\vert dy=1$$ and its support
converge to the origin:
$$\text{supp} \left( f\right) =cl\left\{ x:f_{m}\left(
x\right) \neq 0\right\} $$ In this text, by simple limiting argument we get 
$$\displaystyle
\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty }\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\frac{f_{m}\left( y\right) }{\left\vert x-y\right\vert ^{d-\alpha }}dy=
\frac{1}{\left\vert x\right\vert ^{d-\alpha }}.
$$

Could you explain me how to get the above result?

Comment: Should there be $|f_m(y)|$ in the integral under limit? Could you give page number, just in case?

Comment: Could you fix Latex? Also what is the page number?

Comment: @user32240: Not from exercise, but from page 119

Comment: @PavelM: Page 119

Comment: With all respect I urge you to fix the latex and also I could find nothing relevant on my book's page 119.

Comment: @user32240 I don't find anything horribly wrong with the latex, and I do find the relevant passages on page 119. Are you looking at the right book? It's *Singular integrals and Differentiability properties of functions*. To answer my own question: $f_m\ge 0$, so absolute values are not needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some context: on page 119 Stein shows that the Riesz potential $I_\alpha$ is not bounded from $L^1$ to $L^{n/(n-\alpha)}$. The step in question is how to show that $(I_\alpha f_m)(x)\to |x|^{-n+\alpha}$ pointwise in $\mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$, where $\{f_m\}$ is a sequence that approximates the point mass at the origin. (Then, pointwise convergence + Fatou's lemma imply that $\liminf\|I_\alpha f_m\|_{n/(n-\alpha)}\ge \||x|^{-n+\alpha}\|_{n/(n-\alpha)}=\infty$, as claimed.)

Fix $x\in\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$. By assumption the support of $f_m$ is contained in a small neighborhood of the origin, say $B_r=\{y: |y|<r\}$. For every $y\in B_r$ we have $|x-y|\le |x|+r$ by the triangle inequality. Hence $|x-y|^{-n+\alpha} \ge (|x|+r)^{-n+\alpha}$. Integration yields $$\int |x-y|^{-n+\alpha}f_m(y)\,dy \ge (|x|+r)^{-n+\alpha} \int f_m(y)\,dy=(|x|+r)^{-n+\alpha}$$.
Since $r\to 0$ as $m\to \infty$, this already gives $\liminf_{m\to\infty} I_\alpha f_m(x)\ge |x|^{-n+\alpha}$, which is enough for Fatou. But just for sport, you can also get a bound from the other side and conclude that $\lim_{m\to\infty} I_\alpha f_m(x)=|x|^{-n+\alpha}$.

Comment: What is the hint for get a bound from the other side?

Comment: @beginner What we have so far was obtained from the **triangle inequality** $|x-y|\le |x|+r$. To get a **reverse** estimate, we should use...

Comment: Is it true that we use Holder Inequality?

Comment: @beginner I was hinting at the **reverse triangle inequality**: $|x-y|\ge |x|-r$, and follow the steps as before with inequalities pointing the other way. You need $r<|x|$ for everything to go smoothly, which is not a problem because $x$ is fixed and $r$ goes to zero as $m$ grows.

Comment: so we get $lim sup I_\alpha f_m(x) \leq |x|^{-n+\alpha}$, thus we get the hypothesis of fatou. Thanks for the hint

Comment: @beginner Sure. But as I wrote in my answer, to use Fatou's lemma $\liminf \int  \ge \int \liminf$ we only needed to know that $\liminf I_\alpha f_m\ge |x|^{-n+\alpha}$. The estimate from the other side is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

By a simple limit argument we assume that the simple $f_m$ is simply smooth and satisfies:

- $$\int_{\mathbf R^d} f_m = 1;$$
- $$\lim_{m \to \infty} f_m(x) = \delta(x).$$

So your simple equality states that
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \int_{\mathbf R^d} \frac{f_m(y)}{|x - y|^{d - \alpha}} \textrm{d}y = \int_{\mathbf R^d} \frac{\delta(y)}{|x - y|^{d - \alpha}} \textrm{d}y = \frac{1}{|x|^{d - \alpha}}.$$

**Keywords:** [Friedrichs mollifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier); [mollifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier); [approximative identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_identity); [approximation to the identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_to_the_identity_%28disambiguation%29); [nascent delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nascent_delta_function#nascent_delta_function)

**Beware:** Distributions need nice things to test against. So regularize!

Comment: Yes, this problem is really a problem in distributions.